# How to include a pkcs12 binary file in a Spring Boot tar file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I need to include a binary pkcs12 certificate file in my Spring Boot microservice distributions. I have tried adding it in the root dir and in src/main/resources, but as it's not a text file Gradle returns an error " Could not copy file" (it would be great that Gradle specified why he can't copy it BTW)

How can I include that resource so when I do a Gradle distTar the file is included in the project so builtin Tomcat finds it and https protocol is correctly configured?

Comment: how did you configure your distribution plugin ? by default the dist* task will take resource files located in  /src/main/dist  directory, see : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html#sec:distribution_contents

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it with:

```
processResources {
  // Exclude the certs files to be processed as text
  exclude "**/*.pkcs12"

  // Copy the pkcs12 files to the resources (classpath)
  doLast {
    copy {
      from "src/main/resources/tripbruKeystoreWithKey.pkcs12"
      into "$buildDir/resources/main/"
    }
  }
}
```

Which makes the pkcs12 file end up with the rest of resources. Now I need to find out how to reference if from the properties list, bu