# How to reference a pkcs12 keystore in Spring Boot properties

Tags: docker, spring-boot, pkcs#12

I need to pack a Spring Boot application as a Docker. I have everything running except the inclusion of the pkcs12 keystore needed to have Spring Boot directly support SSL.

I have solved the inclusion of the binary keystore file problem on gradel as explained here:
[How to include a pkcs12 binary file in a Spring Boot tar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079265/how-to-include-a-pkcs12-binary-file-in-a-spring-boot-tar-file/52079859#52079859)

This makes the keystore end up along with the properties files... that is in /BOOT-INF/classes/ directory... which is fine but, how can I have embedded Tomcat find it?

I have tried the properties file:

```
ssl.key-store: /BOOT-INF/classes/tripbruKeystoreWithKey.pkcs12
```

but that won't work. Tomcat won't find it there.

As I see it there are 2 options:

a) Make the keystore be in a different place (I think that if I can make it go to /BOOT-INF/lib it will be correctly recognized just by:

```
ssl.key-store: tripbruKeystoreWithKey.pkcs12
```

b) Correctly set the path in ssl-key-store property so Tomcat finds it in BOOT-INF/classes

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .p12 in the jar will be available as a classpath resource, so you can reference it from your configuration like this:

```
ssl.key-store: classpath:tripbruKeystoreWithKey.pkcs12
```

Comment: @icordoba The thing about Spring Boot is to find the Spring Boot way to do things ;) No need to try to roll your own solutions, they're already implemented.